# Converting case in place

Tags: unicode

Assuming I have an abstract buffer containing a unicode text and I want to convert its case in place. Can I actually do it? Or, in other words: does the unicode standard guarantee that all lowercase/uppercase letter pairs are represented with equal number of code units?

Comment: AFAIK, the only guarantee is that simple case folding can be done in-place with a UTF-16 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the unicode standard guarantee that all lowercase/uppercase
>   letter pairs are represented with equal number of code units?

No. Take the German letter `ß` it's uppercase representation is `SS` and it's foldcase representation, the one you should be using for case insensitive matching, is `ss`

Comment: doesn't `ß` have an uppercase representation `ẞ`?

Comment: @AndreiR. No, while ẞ is indeed called "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S", it is not canonically the uppercase version of ß. One reason for this is that ẞ is exceedingly rare; to a German it looks strange if you have this in a normal sentence.

Comment: @daxim However this question is about Unicode, and if you use the Unicode rules for upper-casing to get the upper case of `ß` you end up with `SS` and not `ẞ`

Comment: Sure, and good programming languages are malleable enough to change that ossified mistake. (I don't blame the Unicode consortium, they got duped.) – Here are some more characters that expand in a similar fashion: `ŉǰΐΰևẖẗẘẙẚὐὒὔὖᾀᾁᾂᾃᾄᾅᾆᾇᾈᾉᾊᾋᾌᾍᾎᾏᾐᾑᾒᾓᾔᾕᾖᾗᾘᾙᾚᾛᾜᾝᾞᾟᾠᾡᾢᾣᾤᾥᾦᾧᾨᾩᾪᾫᾬᾭᾮᾯᾲᾳᾴᾶᾷᾼῂῃῄῆῇῌῒΐῖῗῢΰῤῦῧῲῳῴῶῷῼﬀﬁﬂﬃﬄﬅﬆﬓﬔﬕﬖﬗ`