# .toUpperCase splits some chars in two? Might .toLowerCase do that too?

Tags: javascript, unicode

This morning I was under the impression .toUpperCase and .toLowerCase only translate the basic Latin chars a-z and A-Z and leave the more "exotic" characters alone but of course, on closer inspection, that's really not the case...

```
console.log( "ﬁ".toLowerCase() ); // this yields a single char
>ﬁ

console.log( "ﬁ".toUpperCase() ); // this yields two chars
>FI
```

After reading the specs it seems javascript is applying the *"Unicode Default Case Conversion algorithm"* and it's a whole lot more complicated. The Unicode specs says the various mappings between upper, lower and title case are defined by the two files UnicodeData.txt and SpecialCasing.txt and I don't doubt that, **but** trying to make sense of them enough to answer my question has brought me to the brink of a brain haemorrhage. Before I go any further I thought I would ask if anyone more familiar with Unicode knows...

---

**edit: Thanks for your suggestions so far but THIS is my question...**

Are there any unicode **upper** to **lower** case conversions that might split a character into several chars?

---

And if so, is there a canonical javascript way to do a casing conversion that doesn't split any characters? I want a case conversion method to make a single char substring search case insensitive. Consequently it doesn't matter if the result is a string of mixed case as long as it is consistent i.e. a single character is always translated to a single character, be it upper or lower.

Comment: I don't think there is a guaranteed way to make a mirrored conversion between uppercase and lower case. Not for every single case out there. For example, there is a German character `"ß"` - it's called eszett and it represent double `s`. So `ss = ß` as far as normal reading/writing rules are involved: `Strasse = Straße` in normal usage. But `"ß".toUpperCase()` will convert this single character into `"SS"` because it represents *lowercase* `s`-es, there is no uppercase eszett.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256097/converting-case-in-place/57256360#comment101036451_57256360

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have a problem. Some conversions are required to produce multiple characters. `ß` is a fancy German way to write `ss`, but the upper case letter `ẞ` erroneously does not fall under Unicode's casing rules, so for historic back-compatibility converting to uppercase will make it `SS`. Similarly, `İ` (upper case `i` with dot) lower cases to `i̇` (which unfortunately looks like a normal lower case `i`, but it actually a lowercase `i` followed by a `COMBINING DOT ABOVE`). These are literally the two first examples in Unicode's [`SpecialCasing.txt`](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt).

Point is, sometimes, there is no case folding solution that performs one-to-one character conversions. You need to write your algorithm to handle cases where searching for a single character actually searches for a pair of characters, or just accept that your algorithm isn't portable.

Something like this is the usual solution:

1. [Complete case folding to convert both operands to the most caseless, composed form available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53488013/364696)
2. [Substring search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789952/364696) for the normalized needle in the normalized haystack